# File loaded in hive using Pig/hive mismatch

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

If a file is loaded into hive tables, one by using Pig and one by using hive. How do you make sure that data in both table is same? How do you get the mismatched records from both tables?

Comment: Consider adding query and script u r using

Comment: I didnt understand?Can you explain in detail.

Comment: What u have tried , post it in question.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the loading code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be same, if you want to be sure, run these hive queries:

```
SELECT * from table_pig
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from table_hive)
```

and

```
SELECT * from table_hive
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from table_pig)
```

If the two queries didnt return any record, then both tables are same.

Comment: is minus supported in Hive?